# Сохранение маршрута после перезагрузки, Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Реализую SPA используя Vue, Vuex, Vue-router, Webpack. Для того, чтобы сохранились страницы личного кабинета и маршруты после перезагрузки страницы  использую плагин vuex-persistedstate. Но он вызывает проблему на продакшене - кэширует маршруты. Из-за чего я не могу задеплоить изменившиеся маршруты. Локально такого не происходит.

Как быть в такой ситуации? Отказываться от vuex-persistedstate в пользу чего-то другого?

Comment: Что значит кеширует маршруты? И как плагин для сохранение чего то в куки или локал сторедж, может их кешировать?

Comment: Если плагин установлен. Меняю маршруты. Выкатываю на боевой сервер -  меняются все файлы, все данные. Но маршруты остаются прежними.

Comment: Удаляю плагин. Все работает нормально. Сразу обновляются все маршруты. Но при перезагрузке вылетает из лк. Подключаю плагин обратно - и работают старые маршруты

Comment: Для production нужно всё перестраивать с помощью `npm run build`. И рекомендую использовать CI/CD для того, чтобы ручками не деплоить на сервер вручную.

Comment: Для production собираю проект с помощью команды `npm run build`